# Is there a way to access the devices calendar and add events without having a popup to confirm every event in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, calendar

I want to be able to add multiple events in the background of the app and have tried device_calendar 3.1.0 but on android it pops up a calendar for each event you add. Is there something I can do to this plugin or an alternative plugin that can do what I want?

Comment: List<Calendar> _calendars;
DeviceCalendarPlugin _deviceCalendarPlugin;                                                                      final eventToCreate = new Event(_calendars[1].id);
                      for (int i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
                        eventToCreate.title =  "title";
                        eventToCreate.start = DateTime.parse(event[i].taskDate);
                        eventToCreate.end = DateTime.parse(event[i].taskDate);
                createEventResult=await_deviceCalendarPlugin.createOrUpdateEvent(eventToCreate);
                      }